# How can i Allow user to modify Own Files only Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Storage to store files of the user. My storage structure is as shown below. I want to allow only created file user to modify his files not to others.

```
profiles/uid/posts
```

**posts/** folder contains all his uploaded files. I want to restrict between this path files from other users modification. They can see my all files between **profiles/uid/posts** this path. My current rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Help me to achive this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Identify the per-UID folder like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profiles/{uid}/posts/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I strongly suggest reading more about per-user authentication rules in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security).

Comment: Not able to understand this doc. Real time database rules are appreciable. Thanks a lot

Comment: I found bug. I am not able to upload my file on this rule. But can see all files. What is the problem?

Comment: @SophiaGray I guess it should be `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;` Allow when request.auth.uid is equal to {uid}. Should not be `!=` which means if the UIDs don't match then  allow the procedure

Comment: @Dharmaraj thanks. It works. can you please tell me what is the purpose of /b/{bucket}/o  and {allPaths=**} ?

Comment: @SophiaGray `${uid}` is a wildcard.... means it's value is variable  and not constant and you can compare it as Doug has in his answer. `{allPaths=**}` means the rules apply for everything inside that path

Comment: write: if request.auth.uid == uid works sometimes. I have got Storage Exception not able to load the image file into ImageView using Glide. It works only when i apply rule as shown in my question.